# Mesh shapes keeps changing while rigging

Tags: rigging, sculpting, bmesh

[image]I have checked everything like double vertices but while mesh still keeps on changing its shape when I am trying to change the rotation of bone. Why the mesh is not retaining its shape? 
UPDATE- I corrected the weights by weight painting but now this is occuring. Please check the file i have uploaded.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Your weights are wrong. You can fix it with weight painting.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots i have shared the file

Comment: Inverted normals (in edit mode, select all and Shift+N) and reparent to the armature. That's why Blender fails to calculate weights correctly. But there is also some non manifold parts (edit mode, deselect all, then menu select>all by trait>non manifold). You should correct that. Also it is better to work on a non scaled model to rig it (ctrl+A to apply scale), in particular here because scales in x,y,z are not homogeneous.